# How to put routes in a sub folder without changing the URL in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I have links that currently are in my main path. I would like to group them in a sub folder without changing the urls. For example I have `/income-statement` and I want to put the files in a reports directory. With the nested routes the url becomes `/reports/income-statement`. I tried setting the path on the reports level to be `{path: ''}` but it conflicts with my main route

```
this.route('reports', function() {
  this.route('accounts-receivable')
  this.route('income-statement')
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out I can accomplish this by adding `../` to the beginning of the path

```
this.route('reports', function() {
  this.route('accounts-receivable', {path: '../accounts-receivable'})
  this.route('income-statement', {path: '../income-statement'})
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the path of your group-route to be `/`:

```
this.route('reports', { path: '/' }, function() {
  this.route('accounts-receivable')
  this.route('income-statement')
});
```

Comment: This also causes a conflict with the main route